# Excel - conditional formatting =MOD(ROW(),2)=0

Tags: excel, modulo

I'm hoping that this will be easy, but I couldn't find anything.

I'm doing a simple conditional formatting

```
FORMULA              FORMAT             APPLIES TO
=MOD(ROW(),2)=0      FILL COLOUR        =$A$2:$F$1048576
```

And it works! But it colours everything down to row 1048576
What I'd like to do is edit it so that it ONLY fills in the row (A to f) IF there is data in the A column. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Scott has a solid answer... the issue with your formula, and what it applies to the whole sheet, is that you do not have anything to fix it per row/columns/etc. ("$").  See: https://www.contextures.com/xlCondFormat02.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll definitely read through it

Answer (score 3):

I prefer `ISEVEN`.  But you will want to add another criteria that A is not blank:

```
=AND(ISEVEN(ROW()),$A2<>"")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `ISBLANK` like this `=ISBLANK($A2)=FALSE`

Comment: Both your methods worked perfectly for me! Thanks you!